# My Exe's are viruses?

Tags: exe

So when I send an Exe of a program I made to my friends, Windows says it could be a virus and you have to click run anyway. I don't want people thinking my games are viruses though. Why don't professional games with exes give that warning? How can I fix mine?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the same message will be displayed if you e-mail en .exe from a "professional" game. Windows warns of everything, which ends up with people getting used to click OK without reading warnings anyway...

Comment: Well I'm not talking about emails. Let's say I send the file over media fire or something. When they download it, everything's fine. They click on it, and a big windows 8/10 thing comes up saying its a risk to run it, and you have to click the small options button and run anyway. With a professional game, double clicking it doesn't come up with any warning, it just runs. Here's an example pic - https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-2/

Answer (score 0):

Im also trying to send fun programs to friends. I have heard that the best solution is to send these files as a txt. file and have the receiver turn it back to an exe.